# Python: Delete object referenced from tuple

Tags: python, memory-management, tuples

I have a very large object inside a `tuple` that I would like to explicitly delete. Unfortunately, since tuples are immutable, just doing `del tup[0]` throws:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object doesn't support item deletion
```

I don't actually need `tup` at all anymore, so I could delete the whole thing, I just want to make sure that the large object referenced from `tup` is deleted immediately without waiting for the garbage collector.

Will just deleting `tup` remove it immediately or is there a better way?

Comment: The `del` statement does *not* reclaim memory immediately.

Comment: Which version of Python is this? Memory management in e.g. Jython is going to be completely different from CPython, and the details of how memory is reclaimed depends on the version of the runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del` does *not* reclaim memory. It does not *delete* the object. Depending on whether you remove an index (like `del somelist[0]`), attribute (like `del foo.attr`) or a variable (like `del foo`).

`del` will ***decrement* the *reference counter***, and if the reference counter hits zero, the memory will be reclaimed, usually immediately.

If there are however cyclic references, the garbage collector has to walk by to remove them. So if you absolutely need to remove the large object with the tuple, you can use:

```
import gc

del tup
gc.collect()
```

Note that if other items refer to the large object, it will still not be removed. So make sure that there is only *one* reference.

For simple variables that have no special `del`ete procedure (some have, like closing a file), `del` will thus remove the variable from the local scope, and set the reference count one less than it was before. This will usually be faster than setting the variable to `None` for instance, since in the latter case, it will increment the reference count of the `None` singleton.